# Subscribe in the background instead of redirecting the page

Tags: google-reader

The one annoyance in Google Reader for me is clicking an RSS feed and having it open the Google Reader window. I just want it to subscribe me to the feed without redirecting me to a different page.

Is that possible?

Comment: About what redirect are you asking? There are several "redirects" taking place when you subscribe to a feed in Google Reader.

Comment: What I mean is that I click an RSS feed to add to Google Reader and the browser opens a Google Reader window for me to subscribe. I want to click the RSS feed link and have it subscribe without taking me anywhere else. Much like InstaPaper, for example, shows a quick fading message box when you click the bookmarklet and doesn't disrupt your surfing.

Comment: There's no way around it - it's hard-coded into Google Reader.

Answer (score 1):

If your concern is having to navigate back to the original page, I think the closest functionality you can get is opening the subscription page in a new tab or window. In most modern browsers this can be achieved by clicking the link with the middle mouse button, or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + clicking it. Once you've added to Google Reader, you can then simply <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd> to return to the original page.

As far as I'm aware, it is not possible to bypass this "Add to Google Reader" step.

Comment: Usually I'm clicking the browser toolbar button, which doesn't do that, but oh well. Too bad it's such a PITA.